# How to get AsyncStorage data without waiting in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await

I have trouble trying to retrieve data from AsyncStorage, I can't directly assign a state like that, since it always returns undifined, how can I avoid that?

```
export default class ListTodo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {},
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    //promise 
    GetDataAsyncStorage('@TODOS').then((data) => {
      this.setState({
        data: data,
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    const {data} = this.state;
    console.log(data); // undifined
    return (
      <>
        <Header />
        <View>
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={({item}) => <TodoItemComponent data={item} />}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          />
        </View>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my function to get data from asynStorage

```
export const GetDataAsyncStorage = async (key) => {
  try {
    let data = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    return {status: true, data: JSON.parse(data)};
  } catch (error) {
    return {status: false};
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a state variable isLoading and toggle it after the data is got from AsyncStorage

snack: https://snack.expo.io/@ashwith00/async

code:

```
export default class ListTodo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {},
      isLoading: false,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData = () => {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: true,
    });
    //promise
    GetDataAsyncStorage('@TODOS').then((data) => {
      this.setState({
        data: data,
        isLoading: false,
      });
    });
  };
  render() {
    const { data, isLoading } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {isLoading ? (
          <ActivityIndicator />
        ) : data.data ? (
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item}</Text>}
            keyExtractor={(item, i) => i.toString()}
          />
        ) : (
          <Text>No Data Available</Text>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: check the snack link its working there, and tell what error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Because AsyncStorage itself is asynchronous read and write, waiting is almost necessary, of course, another way to achieve, for example, to create a memory object, bind the memory object and AsyncStorage, so that you can read AsyncStorage synchronously.

For example, using the following development library can assist you to easily achieve synchronous reading of AsyncStorage [react-native-easy-app](https://github.com/chende008/react-native-easy-app/blob/master/README.en-US.md)

```
  import { XStorage } from 'react-native-easy-app';
  import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
  // or import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

   export const RNStorage = {
       token: undefined, 
       isShow: undefined, 
       userInfo: undefined
   };
   
  const initCallback = () => {

       // From now on, you can write or read the variables in RNStorage synchronously
       
       // equal to [console.log(await AsyncStorage.getItem('isShow'))]
       console.log(RNStorage.isShow); 
       
       // equal to [ await AsyncStorage.setItem('token',TOKEN1343DN23IDD3PJ2DBF3==') ]
       RNStorage.token = 'TOKEN1343DN23IDD3PJ2DBF3=='; 
       
       // equal to [ await AsyncStorage.setItem('userInfo',JSON.stringify({ name:'rufeng', age:30})) ]
       RNStorage.userInfo = {name: 'rufeng', age: 30}; 
  };
  
  XStorage.initStorage(RNStorage, AsyncStorage, initCallback);
```